# saved_change_to_* does't work correctly when using "activerecord-typedstore" gem with Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

We are using `activerecord-typedstore` gem with Rails 5.2 application. Everything is fine except the "dirty attributes" methods in after callbacks. According to the gem's page, it should work with Rails 5.2 but there is a simple way to reproduce the issue

I haven't find a way to fix it myself so I posted an issue to the gem's github: https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore/issues/78

This example demonstrates the issue:

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  typed_store :properties do |p|
    p.string :phone
  end

  after_save :debug
  def debug
    puts "saved_change_to_phone #{saved_change_to_phone.inspect}"
  end
end

p = Profile.create(phone: "123")
p.save
p = Profile.last
p.phone = "456"
p.save

# Displays:
# saved_change_to_phone nil
```

Is it possible to get the standard Rails 5.2 behavior for stored attributes in after callbacks? Or maybe there is an alternative gem that I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your example:

The only way I was able to make it work is to disable accessors like so:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  validates :phone, presence: true
  typed_store :properties, accessors: false do |p|
    p.string :phone
  end

  after_save :debug
  def debug
    puts "saved_change_to_phone #{saved_change_to_phone.inspect}"
  end
end
```

The results:

[image: first]
[image: second]

I don't know if this is your desired behaviour though.

Comment: Intersting result. Thank you @mutantkeyboard